# Stuck at order preservation of mapping $\phi : P \rightarrow Q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

I had to show that this is order preserving:

$ P=\{ \mathcal{P}(S); \subseteq \}; |S|>1; \; Q=2 $ and $\phi$ from $P \rightarrow Q$ is defined by
$\\  \phi (U)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & U=S \\
0 & U \neq S\\
\end{array} \right. $

My solution:

$ U,V \subseteq P $ such that $\phi (U) = \epsilon; \; \phi(V)=\delta \\$
$\\ \Leftrightarrow \forall x\in S; \epsilon = 1 \Rightarrow \delta=1
\\ \Leftrightarrow \phi(U) \leq \phi(V)$

I do not understand where to use $0$ in this? According to my solution, this is order preserving.

Comment: I am afraid your solution is not very legible. For $\phi(U), \phi(V)$ to make sense, you need to have $U,V\in P$ rather than $U,V\subseteq P$. Furthermore, where do you use the *ordering* (inclusion) for elements of $P$? What does $\forall X\in S;\epsilon=1\implies\delta=1$ mean?

Comment: @StinkingBishop hey yes. I am sorry for the mistake. I got it! Basically U and V are specific elements of the power sets and not subsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the order to *not* be preserved, we need to have two sets where $U\subseteq V$ but $\phi(U)\not\le\phi(V)$.

The latter is only possible when $\phi(U)=1$ and $\phi(V)=0$. But the former means that $U=S$, which, with $U\subseteq V$ implies $V=S$ and so $\phi(V)=1$ too - a contradiction!

Comment: Following your proof: If my question was $ P=\{ \mathcal{P}(S); \subseteq \}; |S|>1; \; Q=2 $ and $\phi$ from $P \rightarrow Q$ is defined by
 $\\  \phi (U)= 1 , \; U \neq \emptyset \\
\phi(\emptyset)=0 $

Comment: Yep............

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi(U)=\begin{cases}1&&x\in U\\0&&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$? How can you have something on the LHS not depending on any $x$ be defined as something on RHS that depends on some $x$?

Comment: Sorry my bad! I just meant that then any $\phi : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow 2^n$ will be order preserving, where $X=\{1,2,3,4....,n\}$

Comment: Not *any* $\phi$, but this $\phi:\mathcal P(S)\to 2^S$, which is defined as $\phi(U)(x)=\begin{cases}1&&x\in U\\0&&x\not\in U\end{cases}$ *is* an order-preserving bijection, if the order on $2^S$ is established as $f\le g\Leftrightarrow (\forall x\in S)f(x)\le g(x)$.

Comment: Can you please give me an example where $ P=\ \mathcal{P}(S) \; Q=2^s $ and $\phi$ from $P \rightarrow Q$  but $\phi$ is not order preserving?

Comment: Grab one $\phi$ that *is* order-preserving, and then spoil the order, e.g. by inverting it. Say, $\varphi(U)=1-\phi(U)$, meaning $\varphi(U)(x)=1-\phi(U)(x)=\begin{cases}1&&x\not\in U\\0&&x\in U\end{cases}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115995/discussion-between-drumroll-and-stinking-bishop).

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid that I can’t make any sense of your solution. You need to show that if $U,V\subseteq S$ and $U\subseteq V$, then $\varphi(U)\le\varphi(V)$. There are basically just two cases:

- If $V=S$, then $\varphi(V)=1$; $\varphi(U)$ is either $0$ or $1$, so $\varphi(U)\le 1=\varphi(V)$ no matter what $U$ is.
- If $V\ne S$, then $\varphi(V)=0$. Since $U\subseteq V$, we know that $U\ne S$, and therefore $\varphi(U)=0$, too. Thus, once again we have $\varphi(U)\le\varphi(V)$.

Comment: Hence the order is preserved? Can you recommend me some material on this? I have been following Davey and Priestley but it is confusing me

Comment: If instead I have to show:

$ P=\{ \mathcal{P}(S); \subseteq \}; |S|>1; \; Q=2 $ and $\phi$ from $P \rightarrow Q$ is defined by
 $\\  \phi (U)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & x \in U \\
0 & otherwise\\
\end{array} \right. $

Comment: Then my solution above is correct no?

Comment: Also $ U,V$ should be elements of P and not $S$

Comment: @Drumroll: Unfortunately, lattice and order theory is at the periphery of my interests, so while I have some familiarity with it, I don’t really know what’s available in the way of texts. // If your new function $\varphi$ is defined in terms of a single specific $x\in S$, it is indeed monotone, but the proof would be similar the direct argument that I gave or the indirect one that **Stinking Bishop** gave.

Comment: @Drumroll: No, $U$ and $V$ are not elements of $P$: $P$ is an ordered pair whose first component is $\wp(S)$ and whose second component is the subset relation. $U$ and $V$ are elements of $\wp(S)$ and therefore, as I said in my answer, subsets of $S$.

Comment: okay thanks a lot!

Comment: @Drumroll: You’re welcome.